# Цикл не понял смысла

Tags: циклы, javascript

Товарищи, изучаю джаваскрипт, но у меня проблема: я не понял смысла цикла `for` и почему именно i пишется в ее переменной. Объясните, пожалуйста, на простом понятном языке что делает и зачем нужен цикл `for`. Спасибо Всем.

Comment: Про for почитайте [тут][1]. Понятнее некуда. Что касается i, то выбор имени переменной зависит от предпочтений разработчика. Исторически сложилось, что для именования счетчика в цикле for используются переменные, которые называются i, j, k. Они состоят только из одного символа и не несут какой-то особой смысловой нагрузки, что удобно для такой сущности как счетчик. Но это всего лишь традиция. Ничто не мешает вам называть эту переменную как-либо еще.


  [1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/while-for#цикл-for

Comment: > Исторически сложилось

Вы все правильно написали, единственное что остается добавить: 

есть такое понятие как индекс элемента в массиве (en: `index`). Вот почему `i` почала применятся в качестве счетчика для циклов (которые в самом начале оперировали в основном только с массивами, у которого было понятие индекса элемента). Что касается: `j`, `k` - они следуют в алфавите за буквой `i`

Comment: еще  бывает n :)

Comment: @jmu не соглашусь. Почитайте например [здесь][1]


 [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_counter

Comment: @DreamChild, остается решить первая буква имени первой из целых (по умолчанию) переменных в Фортране берет свое начало от `index` или `integer`?

Доказательств не имею, но считаю, что от индекса, точнее от `index register`, целочисленных регистров в некоторых ЭВМ, использующихся про вычислении исполнительного адреса.

Comment: @avp я доказательств тоже не имею, но в приведенной мной  ссылке говорится о двух вариантах - либо от integer, либо вообще из математической нотации, где речь идет об операциях суммирования и произведения, известных из курса матана. Возможно, и в математике эти i происходят от слова index, но все же это уже совсем-совсем другая история, к массивам отношения не имеющая. Кстати, ваш вариант с индексными регистрами тоже вполне правдоподобен. Так или иначе, утверждать что-то здесь сложно

Comment: А я всегда считал что I - это итерация (iteration) я все это время ошибался?

Answer (score 5):

С for проще работать. Он более компактен. Также и проще найти условия и начальные данные.
Набросал картинку. Может так будет удобнее. Кстати "i" - необязательное имя счётчика. Это обычное имя переменной.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

весело )
1 - i там не причем можете использовать любую другую переменную
2 - как бы считается правильнее в js объявлять все переменные в 1 месте, тогда var i как таковой будет чем то просто i = 0
3 - блок работает даже без первой части то есть можно так for (; i< l; i += 1) { ...

теперь зачем оно надо (цикл for)
цикл for дает возможность несколько раз выполнить 1 и те же наборы операнд.
ну например

```
(function() {
   var i = 0,
   l =10;
   for (; i<l; i += 2) {
       alert('цикл переменная i = ' + i);
   }
} ())
```

выведет несколько раз сообщение с текущим значением переменного i
P.S. сколько раз попробуйте догадаться сами )

Answer (score 0):

Типичный цикл в JavaScript:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Инструкция for выполняет блок инструкций (тело цикла) до тех пор, пока указанное выражение (i < arr.length) возвращает true. То есть пока число в переменной i меньше длины массива arr, цикл будет выполнять код заключенный в фигурные скобки снова и снова. Первый параметр объявляет переменную i - это так называемый счетчик (counter). Третьим параметром (i++) мы говорим, что в конце каждой итерации нужно увеличить счетчик на единицу.

Более простым языком: Дан массив arr. Пусть переменная i равна нулю. Пока переменная i меньше длины массива arr, выполнять код в фигурных скобках. В конце каждого прохода увеличить переменную i на единицу.